# how to change data type in javascript input form?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on an apps script project with a spreadsheet as a database.

```
function getFormValues(formObject) {

    /**  ADD OR REMOVE VARIABLES ACCORDING TO YOUR FORM */
    if (formObject.RecId && checkID(formObject.RecId)) {
        var values = [
            [formObject.RecId.toString(),
                formObject.namaAdv,
                formatDate(formObject.tanggal), // Format TANGGAL
                formObject.toko,
                formObject.product,
                parseFloat(formObject.biayaIklan), // Parse BIAYA IKLAN as float
                parseFloat(formObject.penjualanOrg), // Parse PENJUALAN ORGANIK as float
                parseFloat(formObject.qtyOrg), // Parse QTY ORGANIK as float
                parseFloat(formObject.penjualanAds), // Parse PENJUALAN ADS as float
                parseFloat(formObject.qtyAds), // Parse QTY ADS as float
                new Date().toLocaleString()
            ]
        ];
    } else {

        /** Reference https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/51012/244121 */
        var values = [
            [new Date().getTime().toString(),
                formObject.namaAdv,
                formatDate(formObject.tanggal), // Format TANGGAL
                formObject.toko,
                formObject.product,
                parseFloat(formObject.biayaIklan), // Parse BIAYA IKLAN as float
                parseFloat(formObject.penjualanOrg), // Parse PENJUALAN ORGANIK as float
                parseFloat(formObject.qtyOrg), // Parse QTY ORGANIK as float
                parseFloat(formObject.penjualanAds), // Parse PENJUALAN ADS as float
                parseFloat(formObject.qtyAds), // Parse QTY ADS as float
                new Date().toLocaleString()
            ]
        ];
    }
    return values;
}

function formatDate(dateString) {
    const date = new Date(dateString);
    const day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    const month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    return `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
}
```

and I have an input form, one of which is of type date

```
<div class="col">
                            <label>TANGGAL<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
              <div class="input-group input-group">
                <span class="input-group-text"><span class="fa-solid fa-calendar"></span></span>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="tanggal" id="tanggal" onfocus="(this.type = 'date')" required>
                        </div>
```

when the form is successfully submitted, but in the spreadsheet why does the date become plain text (example: when I input 03/23/2024, in the spreadsheet the date becomes '03/23/2024)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1oG7.png)

How do I ensure that the date remains in the date format that I entered when inputting data?

bagaimana caranya agar tanggal tetap dalam format tanggal yang saya masukkan ketika input data?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem may be here

```
const day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
const month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
```

When you have a string and concat it to a date it automatically turns the type into a string. Get rid of the `"0"` and see what happens.